# Building Facebook Chat using Strophe

Tags: xmpp, javascript, javascript-framework, strophe, facebook-chat

I'm trying to use strophe.js to connect to facebook's xmpp servers. I think i need to implement some Connection Manager. can someone point me to some sample code to use strophe.js to implement facebook chat???

PS: Is there a simpler way to implement facebook chat using javascript only...????

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you are still waiting an answer, i posted similar question few days ago, [architecture to Facebook-chat from a webpage, (XMPP? Strophe? Punjab?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897833/architecture-to-facebook-chat-from-a-webpage-xmpp-strophe-punjab) and i got some answer. Still didn't work completely but I am working on it.

I also found some other post that can help [Configuring punjab to send xmpp requests to Openfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013588/configuring-punjab-to-send-xmpp-requests-to-openfire)