# facebook chat using strophe, punjab

Tags: javascript, xmpp, twisted, strophe, facebook-chat

using the answer of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897833/architecture-to-facebook-chat-from-a-webpage-xmpp-strophe-punjab) and [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013588/configuring-punjab-to-send-xmpp-requests-to-openfire) I tried to implement facebook-chat from a browser. Here is what I did:

1. on an ubuntu virtual machine, I have **python 2.6.5**, **python-twisted-conch 1:10.0.0-2**, **python-twisted-names 10.0.0-1**, **python-twisted-web 10.0.0-1** and **python-twisted-words 10.0.0-2** already installed. I **did not** install jabberd2 server, I assumed facebook server is the Jabber/XMPP server in my case. Also I **did not** install pyopenssl.
2. downloaded and untared **punjab** from [here](https://github.com/twonds/punjab)
3. run it using the following command

> ```
> user@ubunto: sudo twistd punjab
> ```

sometimes it tells that the process is already running under PID xxx but most times the reply was

> ```
> Removing stale pidfile /home/user/twistd.pid
> ```

**Does this mean that punjab is running?**

In the punjab.tac file, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013588/configuring-punjab-to-send-xmpp-requests-to-openfire) I change the root.putChild line to

> ```
> root.putChild('bosh', b)
> ```

On the other hand, I have an **apache** server running on the host computer (windows xp) to host my webpage that uses **Strophe**. In the apache config file **httpd.conf**, I proxy the BOSH requests to punjab at port 5280 using:

> ```
> <IfModule proxy_http_module>
>    ProxyRequests Off 
>    ProxyPass /bosh http://ubunto_ipAddress:5280/bosh
>    ProxyPassReverse /bosh http://ubunto_ipAddress:5280/bosh
> </IfModule>
> ```

**Note that** the host and the virtual machine are bridged, so both get their IP address from the router and each one can ping the other. I also didn't install a jabber/xmpp  server, or

For testing, I use the basic example of strophe as my webpage [basic.html](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs/blob/master/examples/basic.html) and [basic.js](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs/blob/master/examples/basic.js) with **JID:** FB_username@chat.facebook.com & **password:** FB_password.

I get the following:

> ```
> Strophe is connecting.
> SENT: <body rid='1709425072' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='chat.facebook.com' xml:lang='en' wait='60' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.6' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
> Strophe is disconnecting.
> ```

**Is there anything wrong or missing?** Please help since I am not finding real documentation other than some posts concerning this issue. Thanks
Sabah

Comment: Did your integration worked , as am stuck at this place where u are so if you have done any progress then please share

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to have a webpage independently connect to Facebook Chat via JS, it's not going to work due to Cross Site Scripting protections. You can only use Strophe to connect to the same server that issued the webpage Strophe is working on.  You'll have to connect back to your server first and use that as an inbetween; or use iframes to embed facebook chat in your webpage.

(For the record, I know nothing about Python, but it looks like your problem is with the JS :) )

Comment: thanks you @Thomas Shields. Yes I am trying to have FB-chat in my webpage, I don't care how it is done (using Strophe, Punjab, iframe, ...). When using strophe, which server did you mean I should connect to, **webserver or another local XMPP server?**
If using iframe is easier, **do you know some pointer (tutorial/example) on how to do that?**
I also know nothing about Python ;) so an easier way is always welcomed.

Comment: @sabah when using Strophe, you can't connect to some other webserver, you have to connect to the server that issued the page. So, you have to connect to YOUR server, not facebook's.  as to iframes, i haven't a clue, but i'm pretty sure Facebook has some information in their dev docs.