# Is it possible to implement facebook chat inside iframe in my own website?

Tags: facebook, iframe, xmpp, facebook-iframe, facebook-chat

I am trying to implement fb-chat from inside my website (in any possible way). Something like in ebuddy or meebo. In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979295/facebook-chat-using-strophe-punjab), I was suggested to use the facebook-chat from within an iframe. I searched for some documentation on how to do that but most of the results show how to make applications in a facebook.

**Please somebody help me in this?** I need some pointers or tutorials from websites which already implemented this. **If not possible,** please suggest another solution. I have been stuck in this for long time.

thanks a lot
Sabah

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be possible and you can implement this by using facebook provided code and its link is

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

kindly check this...

Comment: @Gaurav: i am not sure if you got my problem right, i need to enable FB-chat inside a webpage in a pure web environment (it can be from within an iframe or anything else). I can not run python in my clients since it can be any web-browser enabled device (including smartphones and tablets). Thus no plugins are allowed. Is that possible?